# High-precision timestamp getter, that returns milliseconds as Int64

Tags: c#, .net

Need a high-precision timestamp .NET function

I have used winapi `TimeGetTime`. But it uses `Int32`, cycles every 49.8 days and return can be `signed`.

What is a native .NET high-precision function which return type is `Int64` or `UInt64`, returns milliseconds?

It is not important whether it returns milliseconds from system start or any other time in the past.

Actually I don't need `StopWatch`

**EDIT:**
My application is multithreaded. `StopWatch` instance should be created for every thread. `StopWatch` has a very high-precision timer. I need only 1-5ms.
What I need is something like timeGetTime / Environment.TickCount as Int64 or DateTime.Ticks with update resolution of 1-5ms

Comment: I think you do need `Stopwatch`.

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow` is low precision(~16ms typically), but so it `TimeGetTime`. For high precision you need `StopWatch` but it has its share of issues too, such as desyncs between cores on some (broken) hardware.

Comment: "Actually I don't need StopWatch" - why not, it is closest to what you want.

Comment: @SLaks: I not 100% sure but I think the OP wants a more "accurate" system time, rather than a precise timing function.... i.e. The current date time, but with a high-precision milliseconds count (as in lots of decimal places) - I may be wrong though!

Comment: yep, thats what I do need. To use `StopWatch` you need to create an instance of it. MSDN says only static members of StopWatch can be used thread safe. My program is multithreaded

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with this timer, so we can give you better options?

Comment: @Didar_Uranov Why can't you make a instance per thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows 8 or Server 2012 or higher, use `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` as follows:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
static extern void GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out long filetime);

public DateTimeOffset GetNow()
{
    long fileTime;
    GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out fileTime);
    return DateTimeOffset.FromFileTime(fileTime);
}
```

This has much, much better accuracy than `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`.

See MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks. This is actually more precise than milliseconds.

Comment: You're confusing _precision_ with _accuracy_.  DateTime.Now will not be accurate to within milliseconds.